# Converting HTML to Acrobat

Tags: html, pdf

Is there a way to convert an entire local HTML hierarchy to a set of acrobat documents with the links still active?


I have the entire Android SDK in HTML and would like to convert it to PDF so that I can copy it onto my ebook.


There are also other HTML hierarchies I would like to convert as well.


Would anyone recommend any software that converts document formats, even paid versions. I also have a lot of my Powerpoint presentations I would like to convert.


This is not off topic because I am taking about command references to programming languages and software platforms such as Android.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.iwriteiam.nl/html2tex.html followed by pdflatex.
You might want to use hyperref.

Answer (score 0):

When you convert to pdf, the hyperlinks that point to HTML, now have to point to PDF.
This means the export would have to know the new filenames of the links that now need to point to PDFs.  You're not going to find a export that works on a 'set' of HTML documents.

if you had a single microsoft word file with hyperlinks you could probably do it.